# install a R package from directory

Tags: r, directory, installation, package

Hi is it possible to **install**  an R package directly from a directory without going the intermediate step of building a tar.gz from source and then calling install?

I know that `devtools` support `load_all` but for my purposes (deploying to several opencpu servers) is not sufficient and a "proper" installation is needed.

Comment: This is the solution: install.packages("/myPath/", type = "source", repos=NULL)

Comment: Have you tried `R CMD INSTALL path/to/directory`?

Comment: I have to admit I only tried this with ... /my.tar.gz. but I found the solution -> see comment above. Thank you.