# How to deploy a *.tar.gz package on Opencpu

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, opencpu

I have the following issue:

I created a R package which is ending in *.tar.gz and I want to just upload this to the ubuntu server and install it into opencpu from the servers file system without using github (as Im not familiar with github that much yet).

I have the following configuration:
Ubuntu 14.04 running opencpu /opencpu-cache on it
Installed R
Installed RStudio

I haven't found any guideline which points into this direction. 
Does anyone have some guidance on how a R package (tar.gz) can be installed in Opencpu without using Github?
Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733459/install-a-r-package-from-directory for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about packages that you use with OpenCPU. Install it like any R package:

```
R CMD INSTALL yourpackage_1.2.tar.gz
```

If you are not root and you want to install in the global library you might need `sudo`:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL yourpackage_1.2.tar.gz --library=/usr/local/lib/R/site-library
```

Afterward installing you should be able to interact with the package via e.g.

```
curl http://localhost/ocpu/user/yourname/library/yourpackage/R 
curl http://localhost/ocpu/library/yourpackage/R
```

Comment: Thank you!
Where do I copy the package into such that it can be found? 
Is it in: `/etc/R`

Comment: You don't have to copy it anywhere. After installing it you can delete the source package if you want.

Comment: @Jeroen Is this the only way to deploy an R code to opencpu? I have a simple R script that tests an ODBC connection to Redshift. Should I still have to create an R package? I don't have anything related to R. I am just given the source code and the server to deploy it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you need to create an R package. This is really not difficult. Create an empty package using e.g. rstudio IDE or `package.skeleton()` and then copy your script in the `inst` dir. Or even better: wrap your script into `myfun <- function(){...}` and put it in the `R` dir.